# Expand submenu item to fit header (first right then left)

Tags: html, css

I have the following structure:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="item">
            Menu
            <div class="submenu">
                <div class="submenuitem">Submenu</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and so far the following CSS:

```
div.wrap {
    background: #eee;
    height: 80px;
}

div.menu {
    margin-left: 50px;
    background: #36e;
}

div.item {
    background: #d00;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

div.item:hover {
    background: #b00;
}

div.submenu {
    display: none;
    background: #0b0;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0%;
    top: 50%;
    min-width: 300px;
}

div.item:hover div.submenu {
    display: inline-block;
}

div.submenuitem {
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    background: #b00;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zmcEC/8/)

The behaviour I'm after is that the width of `submenuitem` expands to fit its textual content, but that it can use at most the width of `wrap` for expanding. It should also be positioned directly under `item` unless the width of `submenuitem` will be larger than the distance from its original position to the right end of `wrap`. Thereafter it should expand to the left until it meets the left edge of `wrap`.

As you can see this succeeds perfectly when I can know the distance from `submenuitem`'s original position to the right end of `wrap` by setting `right: 0%; min-width: 300px;` on `submenuitem`, but I want to do this in a way that doesn't require knowing that distance.

I have been trying to craft or find a solution to this for the past few days and have not managed to get any closer. Is it even possible with pure CSS to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you want? check this one nd let me know.

http://jsfiddle.net/zmcEC/9/

```
div.wrap {
    width: 400px;
    background: #eee;
    position: relative;
    height: 80px;
}

div.submenu {
    display: none;
    background: #0b0;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 40px;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: No, the behaviour in my JSFiddle is exactly what I want to happen. The issue is that it requires knowledge of the distance between the initial position and the right edge of `wrap` (`min-width: 300px;`), which is not something I can know in the actual implementation.

Comment: Doesn't expand to the left when it meets the right edge for me. It does for you or do you not check what you code?

Comment: i m not getting what actually your desire result, sorry do it yourself.